# download image from dropbox in cordova app for windows phone

Tags: windows, cordova

I have developed an app in *sencha touch2* and *Cordova* . I want to download image from the *Dropbox* in the app for *windows phone*.

Is it possible to use the *Dropbox* for *Cordova* app in *Windows phone*?

Any help will be appreciated.